# Use of Doctrine 2 in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I would like to use Doctrine 2 in ZF2 project. I have done some researches. I found this:
http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/

Unfortunately, I don't have CURL nor composer installed. And when I tried to install CURL first. I had errors i don't manage to solve.

Is there an easy solution to integrate Doctrine 2 in ZF2 ?

Comment: This really seems like an XY problem. Why not try posting on SuperUser to see if you can solve the install issues with Curl rather than trying to find a (potentially bad) workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of days trying to find a good solution to integrate Doctrine 2 into ZF2. Finally, I managed to do it with this skeleton application: https://github.com/iwalz/zf2-doctrine2-getting-started

It has a very good readme, if you follow the steps, success is guaranteed!

Answer (score 1):

You have the official Doctrine ZF2 Module written by Doctrine team

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule

Composer or CURL are a easy way of download that sources and register the namespace. You can do the same downloading the sources and registering the module

Comment: Thank you, could you just tell me how to register this module in my project ?

Comment: The articule which you mention in your question explain how to do it. "Configure Doctrine".

Edit $PROJECT_DIR/config/application.config.php and add DoctrineModule

Comment: Well, this might be a bit weird for you but i don't have any config.php in my ZF2 project. Only a application.ini file which doesn't contain any modules :s

Comment: You should have this file https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/application.config.php

Comment: Stange, have a look at my project architecture
http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/5306/stackb.png

Comment: Seems that you asked to Netbeans make a Zend Project. Netbeans only supports ZF1. You need clone the repository of my last link and start from there

Comment: Actually, i created my project just following this tutorial:
http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/
this is ZF1?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16649/discussion-between-maks3w-and-arnaud-ad)